# Can't log in with user of role db_owner

Tags: sql-server

I'm running the following script and receive no errors nor warnings. I also verify that the user actually has been created. When I click on it, I get to see the roles (the membership *db_owner* is checked).

```
create login normalLogin
  with password = 'normalpass',
  check_policy = off
create login adminLogin
  with password = 'adminpass',
  check_policy = off

create user common for login normalLogin;
create user admin for login adminLogin;

execute sp_addrolemember db_owner, admin
```

However, when I try to log in to the server using *admin* as user name and *adminpass* as password (SQL authorization), I get the error message telling me this.

> Login failed for user 'admin'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Accessing the [helping link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476), I get two feasible suggestions.

1. Verify that SQL Server is configured in Mixed Authentication Mode.
2. Verify that SQL Server login exists and that you have spelled it properly.

I'm certain that (1) is correct (still, how can I re-check it?) so the suspicions fall on (2). Is the script above insufficient? I have the feeling that maybe the user on DB level isn't enough and that I need to create it on server level. Is it so? How can I script such an operation? I wish, of course, to keep the security tight and compartmentalized.

Comment: Try logging in with the user under whose login/credentials you ran the script via SQL Management Studio and under Server properties, check if Mixed Mode authenication is enabled. That should be the issue.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: @GaneshR. It's checked, as I thought, on *SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode*. What can I do about the user created by the script?

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log.  It may contain more information as to the reason for the login failed and confirm the authentication mode is set to mixed.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've checked that the user created is supposed to use mixed mode. I still get the error presented. In the logs, the same error is listed. Perhaps there's another "log" that you refer to? Where/how do i check *your* logs?

Comment: The SQL Server error log is located in the instance installation directory by default (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`).  The current log is named `errorlog` (no extension) and older versions are numbered.  You can also view the error log from SSMS Object Explorer under `Management-->SQL Server Logs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this:

1. Open your SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Database server right click and go to properties.
3. Choose Security option and check SQL Server and Windows authentication mode.
4. Enable TCP/IP connection in SQL Configuration Manager.
5. Restart your SQL server service.